# How can I modify the same value in the same file across multiple commits while preserving the commit log?

Tags: git

I have a private project with 10 commits. In each commit, I have committed my API token which I would like to change before I make the project public.

It's held in a simple variable: `const token = 'Token ...'` where `'...'` represents the API token.

Is it possible to automate going through the same file for each commit, updating the value of the variable (for now just to a placeholder value) and preserving the structure of the log, i.e. keep the commit history; the hashes can change.

Right now I can only think of two ways of doing it:

- Just squash all the commits and make the change in a single file. Will do this if there's no way to accomplish the above.
- Manually check out each commit and change it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+password+history

Comment: @phd - Thank you, yes it does. This question can be closed as a duplicate.